# Is the multiplicative group on the complex numbers isomorphic to the multiplicative group on the complex numbers mod all the roots of unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

As the title suggests, I am trying to figure out if $$\mathbb{C}^\times/\mu_\infty \simeq \mathbb{C}^\times$$
My intuition suggests that these two groups are not isomorphic, but I cannot find any contradiction when attempting to construct such an isomorphism. I am aware that $\mathbb{C}^\times \simeq \mathbb{C}^\times / \mu_n$ for finite n, but sensibly the same isomorphism cannot be used. Where do I even start to find such a contradiction, or am I off entirely and these are indeed isomorphic?

To clear up any possible confusion $\mu_\infty = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \mu_n$ where $\mu_n = \{z \in \mathbb{C}^\times : z^n =1 \}$.

Comment: Does $\Bbb C^\times/\mu_\infty$ have any elements of order $2$?

Comment: What is $\mu_\infty$?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I suspect that $\mu_n$ is supposed to denote the subgroup of $n$th roots of unity, and that $\mu_\infty = \bigcup_{n\ge 1} \mu_n$. It would be helpful if this were clarified in the text of the question.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently,  $\Bbb C^×/\mu_{\infty}$ doesn't have any elements of finite order greater than $1$.  So they can't be isomorphic.

Comment: Because $\Bbb{C}^\times/\mu_\infty$ is torsion free abelian group it is a $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space so $\mathbb{C}^\times/\mu_\infty \cong \Bbb{Q}^{\omega_1}$ ?

Comment: @reuns I wish I knew.  I'll get back to you if I figure it out.

Comment: @reuns One can define division $x/n$ in $\mathbb C^\times / \mu_\infty$ by choosing any of the $n$ roots $\sqrt[n]{x}$, which are equal after we modded out by $\mu_\infty$. So, yes, this group has a natural structure of $\mathbb Q$-vector space, thus by the axiom of choice has to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Q^{\mathfrak c}$. Whether $\mathfrak c = \omega_1$ is subject to the continuum hypothesis.