# Is $G\cong \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ under complex multiplication ?yes/no

Tags: group-theory

Given   $G= \{ z \in \mathbb{C} |  \exists \ n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+} \text{such that} \ z^n=1\} $

Is $G\cong \mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ under complex multiplication? yes/No

**My attempt** : I thinks No

Here $G$ is cyclics  but  $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ is not cyclics

so $G$ not isomorphics to  $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$

Comment: $G$ is not cyclic either.

Comment: @Gae.S.  $G$ consists of all $n$-roots of unity for some positive integer $n$.  Any element of $G$ can be uniquely written as $e^{({\frac{2i\pi k}{n}})}$ for some $k\in \{ 0,\ldots ,n-1\}$ that is prime with $n$. 


$\exp\left( \frac{2k\pi i}{n}\right)^n=\exp\left( \frac{2\pi ki}{n}\cdot n\right)=\exp(2\pi k i)=1$

So  $G$ is a cyclic group

Comment: What's your argument? Where does the "So $G$ is a cyclic group" come from?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3349199/is-the-multiplicative-group-on-the-complex-numbers-isomorphic-to-the-multiplicat) for the quotient $\Bbb C^{\times}/G$. Here $G=\mu_{\infty}$. Since the quotient is not trivial, the answer is NO.

Comment: @jasmine I think your statement starts on Thursday and ends on Monday. More specifically, on Thursday "$G$ consists of all $n$-roots of unity for some positive integer $n$" means $[\forall x\in G,\exists n>0, x^n=1]$, while on Monday it means $[\exists n>0, \forall x\in G, x^n=1]$.

Comment: im really soory   u r right @Gae.S. my bad thinking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Group $G$ is a torsion group, i.e. each element has finite order.

On the other hand $\mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$ is not torsion, e.g $2^k \neq 1$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z_{>0}$.

So the two groups cannot be isomorphic.